# Google One-tap SMS verification with the SMS User Consent API Error: Status{statusCode=SUCCESS, resolution=null}

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-api, broadcastreceiver

I wanted to implemented this API for OTP verification in my app, to ask for user's consent to read the verification code from the text message sent from the server(Firebase) and I've followed all the guidelines from the Google API guide(https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/user-consent/request). Here's the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/user-consent/overview)

**OTPVerification** activity is where i want to implement this functionality. When the OTP is sent successfully from the server and the user is taken to **OTPVerification** activity from Login activity the app crashes.

Here's screenshots of debug screen
[image]

[image]

Here's my logcat screenshot where the app crashes
[image]

**OTPVerification** activity code

```
class OTPVerification : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val SMS_CONSENT_REQUEST = 2
    private val TAG = "OTPVerification"
    private lateinit var otpPinView: PinView

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_o_t_p_verification)

        otpPinView = findViewById(R.id.otp_pin_view)
        val otpSentToTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.otp_sent_to_tv)
        val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.otp_verification_toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

        SmsRetriever.getClient(this).startSmsUserConsent(57575454.toString())
        val intentFilter = IntentFilter(SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION)
        registerReceiver(smsVerificationReceiver, intentFilter, 0)

        val intent = intent
        val userFullMobileNumber = intent.getStringExtra("userMobileNo")
        otpSentToTextView.text = resources.getString(R.string.otp_sent_to, userFullMobileNumber)
    }
    private val smsVerificationReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            if (SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION == intent.action) {
                val extras = intent.extras
                val smsRetrieverStatus = extras?.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_STATUS) as Status

                when (smsRetrieverStatus.statusCode) {
                    CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS -> {
                        // Get consent intent
                        val consentIntent : Intent? =
                            extras.getParcelable(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_CONSENT_INTENT)
                        try {
                            // Start activity to show consent dialog to user, activity must be started in
                            // 5 minutes, otherwise you'll receive another TIMEOUT intent
                            startActivityForResult(consentIntent!!, SMS_CONSENT_REQUEST)
                        } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: ${e.message}")
                        }
                    }
                    CommonStatusCodes.TIMEOUT -> {
                        Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Session timed out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        when (requestCode) {
            SMS_CONSENT_REQUEST ->
                // Obtain the phone number from the result
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                    // Get SMS message content
                    val message = data.getStringExtra(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_SMS_MESSAGE)
                    // Extract one-time code from the message and complete verification
                    // `message` contains the entire text of the SMS message, so you will need
                    // to parse the string.
                    val oneTimeCode = parseOneTimeCode(message)
                    otpPinView.setText(oneTimeCode)
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Unable to detect OTP. Please enter OTP manually.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
        }
    }

    private fun parseOneTimeCode(message: String?): Int {
        return message!!.substring(0..5).toInt()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        unregisterReceiver(smsVerificationReceiver)
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should request the server to send you the OTP using an API of the service you are using.

So the steps are:

- You start listening to the OTP using the consent API
- Once it is successfully listening, you request your OTP

```
private lateinit var task: Task<Void>

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   ...
   setOtpReceiver()
   ...
   btnSendOtp.setOnClickListener {
      requestOtp()
   }

 }

 private fun setOtpReceiver() {
        task = SmsRetriever.getClient(this.parentActivity).startSmsUserConsent(null)
 }

 private fun requestOtp() {
        task.addOnSuccessListener {
            // Here you call the Request OTP API 
        }
        task.addOnFailureListener {
            Log.e("Retrieving OTP Error", it.message.toString())
        }
 }
```